# Using Loops in one Table through other Table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

There are two Tables A & B.

Table A:

[image]

Table B

[image]

Now, the conventional and the messy SQL to get the desired output looks as follows:

```
select person, discount from a where Age >18 and category = 'Gold'
union all
select person, discount from a Age = 18 and category = 'General'
```

Table A includes multiple other characteristics/measures for person and is of 1 Million in rows.

Table B contains multiple rules for the discount calculation.

Currently, I am solving this through manually using the union all statement.

Please advice if any PL/SQL or stored proc may be using over Amazon Redshift to resolve the same.

Comment: How is table B involved? (Only table A is used above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, whatever you do - you'll need dynamic SQL because otherwise you can't use those filters. One option might be a function that returns ref cursor.

As you hardcoded columns to be returned (by the way, query you posted is invalid; there's no `discount` column in `tablea` - it belongs to `tableb` so you'll need a join), I did the same. Note that - as it is dynamic SQL - you can store the `select` column list, `from` clause, just as you stored the filter (`where` clause, basically) and have *everything* dynamic.

OK, here we go. Sample tables first:

```
SQL> select * from tablea;

PERSON            AGE CATEGORY
---------- ---------- ----------
A                  18 General
B                  20 Genera
C                  30 Silver
D                  40 Silver
E                  50 Bronze
F                  60 Gold

6 rows selected.

SQL> select * from tableb;

FILTER                       DISCOUNT
-------------------------- ----------
Age>18 and category='Gold'        500
Age=18 and category='Gold'       1000

SQL>
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_amazon
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc     sys_refcursor;
  5    l_str    varchar2(32000);
  6  begin
  7    for cur_r in (select b.filter from tableb b) loop
  8      l_str := l_str ||
  9             'select a.person, a.age, a.category, b.discount ' ||
 10             '  from tablea a join tableb b on ' || cur_r.filter     ||
 11             '  union all ';
 12    end loop;
 13
 14    l_str := rtrim(l_str, '  union all ');
 15
 16    open l_rc for l_str;
 17    return l_rc;
 18  end;
 19  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_amazon from dual;

F_AMAZON
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

PERSON            AGE CATEGORY     DISCOUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
F                  60 Gold              500
F                  60 Gold             1000


SQL>
```

The result is here, so I guess it kind of *works*.

Comment: Please help me with the database being used here. Just wondering if the given snippet will work for Amazon Redshift also.

Comment: Yes, if database is Oracle. I presumed it was as your question specifies "PL/SQL or stored proc", where "PL/SQL" means Oracle's procedural extension to SQL.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. Just wondering if the dynamic SQL  may be generated through Amazon Redshift also  through UDFs. Please check sharing the snippet if possible. Sorry for asking the naive question.

Comment: I wouldn't know, sorry.